# Autoincrementing for each primary key in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I autoincremented a row in Postgres with the SERIAL statement. That work's fine so far, but I want to auto increment for each Primary Key. How do I solve that?

```
CREATE table snapshot(tracking_number varchar(20), 
                      counter SERIAL, 
                      date date, 
                      time time, 
                      status varchar(100), 
                      PRIMARY KEY(tracking_number, counter));
```

For example, with each new entry the counter increments, but I want every entry with each primary key start with 1 and increment only if the same primary key is inserted again.

```
insert into snapshot(tracking_number, date, time, status) values (‘123’, ‘2018-05-05’,’09:00’, ‘mystatus’);

insert into snapshot(tracking_number, date, time, status) values (‘999’,‘2018-05-05’,’09:00’, ‘mystatus’);
```

These two inserts should lead to two entries with having a counter as 1

```
insert into snapshot(tracking_number, date, time, status) values (‘999’,‘2018-05-05’,’09:00’, ‘mystatus’);
```

Inserting again '999' should yield a the counter for '999' as 2, the counter for '123' should still be 1

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Im not sure what you want, please show an example

Comment: Again, show us an example. But if you want what I think you want. That cant be done in table definition. You may need a trigger to change that counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with serial. So I suggest you use triggers.

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON snapshot
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE snapshot_insert()
```

trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION snapshot_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   _counter bigint := (SELECT COALESCE(max(counter), 0) + 1
                       FROM   snapshot
                       WHERE  tracking_number = NEW.tracking_number);

   NEW.counter := _counter;

   RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: That is not going to work in a system where multiple transactions are inserting data. (Btw: you don't need the intermediate variable, you can use `select coalesce(..) into new.counter from ....` directly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was thinking the same but haven't been able to setup a sqlFiddle to test it. Have any suggestion for a workaround?